# Flask_testing Returns 404 unexpectedly for seemingly working endpoint

Tags: python-3.x, flask, python-unittest, flask-testing

Writing some unit tests for my flask application. The endpoint '/' works and returns 200 when I try in postman, however flask_testing gives `AssertionError: 404 != 200`

I have set up a base config.

```
class BaseTestCase(TestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///:memory:"
        app.config['JWT_SECRET_KEY'] = environ['JWT_SECRET_KEY']
        db = SQLAlchemy(app)
        db.init_app(app)
        return app
```

This is the test.

```
class FlaskTestCase(BaseTestCase):

    def test_root(self):
        response = self.client.get('/')
        self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
```

Output from tests

```
======================================================================
FAIL: test_root (test.server-test.FlaskTestCase)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/my_name/path/to/my_project/test/server-test.py", line 13, in test_root
    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)
AssertionError: 404 != 200

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.032s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Comment: Where are routes added?

Comment: They're in src/server.py

Comment: Are they being added in your test file?

Comment: I'm not sure how I would add them. If I look at this example here https://github.com/realpython/discover-flask/blob/master/tests/test_basic.py the subjects under test are not explicitly imported.

Comment: I can only help you by looking at the app structure and code. From given information I think routes are not being added in your tests code.

Answer (score 1):

in my case I had this if statement in the route I was testing

```
if len(books_per_request) == 0:
   response = make_response(jsonify(message="value exceeded books count"), 404)
```

While it successful request I sent 404 error for that reason when test run and count len == 0 it keep return the error if this your first test like me check with normal route that return normal string if every thing ok , check your home route '/'

1. make sure it exist in your **init**.py file
2. and make sure it not return any 404 errors

I hope this help anyone